# Coloumn header shows table name too

Tags: ms-access-2013

I struggle on a small problem with `MS Access (2013)` and a listbox populated with a query.

The query gathers information from `4` different tables which are linked with unique keys. The results are correct but the coloumn header looks weird. One of them is correct (shows only the field name) and 2 are not (the table name is displayed too).

**Shouldn't it be only the field name?**

**If so, how do I can fix that?**

Comment: These col-names are duplicate in the tables. To specify the correct one the tablename is added. You can work around by using an alias e.g.:`SELECT myTable1.myField1 AS mField1, myTable2.myField1 AS mField2 FROM myTable1 LEFT JOIN myTable2 ON myTAble1.id = myTable2.id;`

Comment: Thank you, exactly that's my problem! Gonna mark your answer as soon as I have my laptop ( cant do it with the Android App)

Answer (score 0):

These column-names are duplicate in the tables. To specify the correct one the tablename is added. You can work around by using an [alias](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms187455(v=sql.105).aspx) e.g.:

```sql
SELECT 
    myTable1.myField1 AS mField1,
    myTable2.myField1 AS mField2 
FROM 
    myTable1 
LEFT JOIN 
    myTable2 ON myTable1.id = myTable2.id;
```

Where as mFieldX is the alias, could be used for tables too.